# mysql custom grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an audits table that has a `created_at` column and need to show the number of audits for each year, but my client year from April to April.

For example, the result must show:

```
2011/2012 :10 // this is the range between April-2011 to April-2012
2012/2013 :5  // this is the range between April-2012 to April-2013
```

and so on...

Comment: Is `created_at` a proper `DATETIME` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `GROUP BY` may contain an arbitrary expression, you might use some date manipulation to make each `created_at` value behave as though it is a January-December year.  You may do that by subtracting 3 months from it, so those after April will result in the current year, and those before April will result in the previous year. Wrapping that expression in `YEAR()` will then group them on the calculated value.

```
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

For example, on or after April 1 returns the current year:

```
SELECT YEAR('2015-04-01' - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
+---------------------------------------+
| YEAR('2015-04-01' - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                  2015 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

And earlier returns the previous year for grouping:

```
SELECT YEAR('2015-03-01' - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
+---------------------------------------+
| YEAR('2015-03-01' - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                  2014 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Here's a little sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6cca/1